# Issue saving informations in OAuth consent screen

Tags: google-oauth, registration, google-api-console

I' ve created a new AoG project and then I've enabled API from Google API console. To complete this I have to add informations in OAuth consent screen but I'm having the same error from days: "Failure to save" without explaination about it. I've tried both to add all the informations and only the few required (name and emails) but it still doesn't work. Someone have the same issue? Solutions?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but try changing the application name. I was trying to create an OAuth consent screen and it failed many times with the same error as you. I was trying to name the project "Google Play Console" and it failed. I then tried "google-play-console" and it still failed. Then I tried just "play-console" and it succeeded. I think some words are not allowed, like "google".

Comment: There was a Google service error, not depending on me. After few days everything was fine!

Answer (score 0):

There was a Google service error, not depending on me. After few days everything was fine!